# Optimizing SQL query with multiple joins and conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I'm trying to figure out a way to optimize my query as it is taking more than 48 hrs to execute the script as I have a huge database. I tried creating all possible indexes in the required tables. I even tried to break the query into sub queries but still no luck with the improve in execution time. Any comments or ideas are appreciated. Here is my query :

```
SELECT  distinct
    etb.ID_Etab AS Siret
    ,ctt.DebutCTT AS DateMouvement
    ,ctt.L_Contrat_SQN
    ,ctt.Numero 
    ,ctt.DebutCTT
    ,ctt_pcs.PcsEse
    ,ctt.DerDSN
    ,ctt.H_Etab_SQN
    ,ctt.H_Salarie_SQN
    ,ISNULL(ctt_nat.Nature, '') AS Nature,
    ctt_dpp.DispPolitiquePublique,
ctt_det_exp.DetacheExpatrie,
ctt_SS.StatutSalarie,
ctt_stat.CodeStatutEmploi,SSS.Num_Inscr AS NIR_RECODE
FROM [dbo].[Lnk_Contrat] AS ctt
INNER JOIN [dbo].[LSat_Contrat_Etab] AS ctt_etb ON ctt.L_Contrat_SQN = ctt_etb.L_Contrat_SQN
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Hub_Etab] AS etb ON ctt_etb.Siret = etb.ID_Etab
INNER JOIN [dbo].[LSat_Contrat_PcsEse] AS ctt_pcs ON ctt.L_Contrat_SQN = ctt_pcs.L_Contrat_SQN and ctt.DebutCTT BETWEEN ctt_pcs.Debut AND ctt_pcs.Fin
INNER JOIN [dbo].[LSat_Contrat_Nature] AS ctt_nat ON ctt.L_Contrat_SQN = ctt_nat.L_Contrat_SQN  AND ctt.DebutCTT BETWEEN ctt_nat.Debut AND ctt_nat.Fin AND ISNULL(ctt_nat.Nature, '') <>03
LEFT join Sat_Salarie_SNGI SSS ON SSS.H_Salarie_SQN=ctt.H_Salarie_SQN AND ctt.DebutCTT BETWEEN SSS.Debut AND SSS.Fin
Left JOIN dbo.LSat_Contrat_DispPoliPub AS ctt_dpp ON ctt_dpp.L_Contrat_SQN = ctt.L_Contrat_SQN  
INNER JOIN dbo.LSat_Contrat_DetacheExpatrie AS ctt_det_exp ON ctt_det_exp.L_Contrat_SQN = ctt.L_Contrat_SQN AND ctt.DebutCTT BETWEEN ctt_det_exp.Debut AND ctt_det_exp.Fin
INNER JOIN dbo.LSat_Contrat_StatutSalarie AS ctt_SS ON ctt_SS.L_Contrat_SQN = ctt.L_Contrat_SQN AND ctt.DebutCTT BETWEEN ctt_SS.Debut AND ctt_SS.Fin
LEFT JOIN dbo.LSat_Contrat_StatutEmploiSalarie AS ctt_stat ON ctt_stat.L_Contrat_SQN = ctt.L_Contrat_SQN AND ctt.DebutCTT BETWEEN ctt_stat.Debut AND ctt_stat.Fin
WHERE
    ctt.Creation_DTS > '1900-01-01'
    AND ctt_etb.Debut = '1900-01-01'
    AND ctt_etb.[Type] = 'AF'
    AND ctt.DebutCTT >= ctt_etb.Debut 
    AND ctt.DebutCTT >= etb.PreDSN
    AND ctt.debutCTT>=DATEADD(MONTH, -1, ctt.PreDSN)    
    AND ((ctt.DebutCTT BETWEEN ctt_dpp.Debut AND ctt_dpp.Fin) or ctt_dpp.Fin is null)
order by Siret,L_Contrat_SQN
DBCC TRACEOFF (610)
```

Comment: Have you seen the explain plan?

Comment: Probably you would like don't use Between for optimization. See execution plan as clinomaniac proposed.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?  Your question has both tagged.

Comment: Maybe you should try posting a question on Stack overflow or similar, explaining what the problem and providing the relevant information for other people to advise - like explain plans, table and index structure, index cardinality metrics, But do make sure you don't do something silly like adding irrelevant tags.

Comment: Remove `DISTINCT` and you will literally see the most of problem. The rest of it is in the `WHERE` clause and probably in data model.

Comment: That is hard to read.  With better formatting questions get better response.

Comment: Is using GROUP BY searches the result faster than DISTINCT ?

Answer (score 0):

Into the Sql Server Management Studio paste the SQL sentence and click on "Display Estimated Execution Plan". It shows how Sql Server will try to execute your sentence analyzing exiting indexes of your Where(s) and Join(s).

[image]

Also try to upgrade your hardware, so each Sql sentence may required a huge ammount of memory and cpu cycles depending of the number of records.

Comment: I saw the Execution Plan and added all the required indexes still no improvement in the performance.